# Why are my floats not printing in C but my ints are?

Tags: c, embedded, printf, uart

My floats aren't printing to the console in C and I don't know why. `ints` print fine so I'm confused why floats are. Code below:

```
float temp = 9.5;
u8_t buf[strlen("temp (K): %.2f\n") + strlen(temp)];
sprintf(buf, "temp (K): %.2f\n", temp);
cli_output(buf);
```

In `cli_output`:

```
void cli_output(u8_t buf[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)
    {
        uart_poll_out(comm_uart, buf[i]);
    }
}
```

My output: `Fuel gauge temp (K):` 
Edit: If I have the code below it prints as expected to the console.

```
int temp = 9;
u8_t buf[strlen("temp (K): %d\n") + strlen(temp)];
sprintf(buf, "temp (K): %d\n", temp);
cli_output(buf);
```

Comment: `strlen(temp)` is wrong because `temp` is not string. How do you print ints?

Comment: @MikeCAT Just edited my post to include how I print `int`s

Comment: Even if `strlen(temp)` were able to get the length correctly, there are no room for terminating null-character in `buf`.

Comment: @MikeCAT adding `strlen("\0")` doesn't help either. I also tried adding an arbitrary amount to the buf size but it still doesn't print

Comment: I'm surprised this code doesn't crash.

Comment: @dbush why do you think that?

Comment: Check your manual. Printing float is not supported in some embedded environments.

Comment: @PurpleSpark You're passing either an `int` or a `float` to a function that expects a `char *`.  Actually, this code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: `u8_t buf[strlen("temp (K): %.2f\n") + strlen(temp)];`  This line is wrong on many levels. Do not use `sprintf` prefer using `snprintf`. What platform are you programming on? What compiler, compiler options and compiler version are you uding? If you are programming on some bare-metal target, most probably you are using newlib and did not used `-uprintf_float` (or something like that).

Comment: regarding: `float temp = 9.5;`  the literal `9.5` is a `double`, not  a `float`  Suggest:  `float temp = 9.5f;`  Note the trailing `f` that causes the compiler to output a `float`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buf); i++)`  1) This results in the function: `strlen()` to be executed over and over and over.  2)  function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`  Suggest: `size_t len = strlen( buf );   for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array length issues aside, what can cause this is a development environment that doesn’t have float printf support enabled. Eclipse has a UI setting for this in certain environments — I’ve seen it in Simplicity Studio. Or you can manually add the linker option -u _printf_float

[image: Using Eclipse to add float printf support]

Comment: Yeah this is the issue I was having. Turns out I don't have enough flash to even support that (I tried adding and it overflowed) so I resorted to making my own function to print floats :)

Comment: I remember it added ~10-12 KBytes on the ARM (SiLabs BlueGecko) project I was working on.

Comment: I only have 32kb and it's mostly full unfortunately. Thank you for the help anyway!

Answer (score 3):

`strlen()` is for measureing length of strings, not integers nor floats.

`snprintf()` function returns the length of string to be written, so you can use that for the allocation.

Also don't forget to allocate for terminating null-character.

```
float temp = 9.5;
const char* message = "temp (K): %.2f\n";
int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, message, temp);
u8_t buf[length + 1];
sprintf(buf, message, temp);
cli_output(buf);
```

Comment: I tried this but my program is not getting past the line `sprintf(buf, message, temp);`. I'm not sure why

Comment: @PurpleSpark What version of C are you using?  Try C99.

Comment: Careful, especially with "Freestanding Environments" as by the C Standard, (normal for embedded systems), and especially without dynamic memory allocation, "Variable Length Arrays" (like your `u8_t buf[length+1]` ) might not be supported and could cause crashes. Because the array is not determined at compile time but runtime. How they are implemented is dependent on the implementation (your compiler).

Comment: @kesselhaus that is not an example of "dynamic memory allocation" in the usual meaning of the word, the array will be located on the stack not in the heap.  Exceeding the available stack space is a risk, memory fragmentation, etc is not.

Comment: While this posting is not *wrong* it deals only in tangential errors, not the ultimate problem which is that the asker's embedded environment is (rather typically) missing floating point support in printf() etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: No, this is an VLA, the length info is determined at runtime, and it is nowhere specified, how VLAs are allocated, only about their lifetime. They could be on stack in some implementations, but I had also one (think it was a Tasking compiler) where this was done with malloc/free behind the scene, and this caused an exception due to missing a configured heap. A common misunderstanding is, that the C standard does not say anything about stack or heap, but only about storage duration/lifetime of an object.

Comment: @kesselhaus in reality it is quite obviously on the stack, if you cannot come to terms with that reality, I'm not sure there's much help for you.  The far more important reality is that the actual issue of the question identified in the correctly accepted answer is entirely distinct and far simpler, something you are quite unhelpfully distracting from.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: In reality it is NOT obviously on the stack. The compiler implementation can use anything can use anything for automatic storage duration. Or even state, it does not support VLA at all (__STDC_NO_VLA__ defined as 1). And I definitely had at least one compiler using malloc/free as implementation behind the scene, which got me a reset of the ECU due to memory access exception.

Comment: @kesselhaus - you continue ignoring the obvious facts - the fact that the same VLA code works with ints but not floats demonstrates that the actual issue is what embedded developers of actual experience identified long ago.  And then there's the reality of what the *available* compiler is known to do.  So yes, it's on the stack... a fact you can easily verify with the debugger or by building in some debug output.  Knowing your tools is a good idea; but so is recognizing the *actual* issue.